# How to place certain text in react native

Tags: react-native, text

I am trying to place some text in react native using the `Text` component and I am wondering how I would go about using it to place `<->` in text in react native. I have tried placing it in the `Text` component like this

```
<Text><-></Text>
```

but this leads to errors and the app crashing.

the output I would like is for the text to look like this

```
Process 1 <-> Process 2
```

but errors come up instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only character that cannot be rendered normally in a Text it's **`<`** so you must put it inside curly braces as you were passing a variable.

**Bad**

```js
<Text><</Text>
```

**Good**

```js
<Text>{'<'}</Text>
```

Therefore you can do something like this:

```js
<Text>Process 1 {'<'}-> Process 2</Text>
```

or like this:

```js
<Text>{'Process 1 <-> Process 2'}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the back quote `` to achieve what you want. Inserting reserved characters (< or >) as plain text can be done as shown below:

```
<Text>
   {`Process 1 <-> Process 2`}
</Text>
```

That should work as you intend

Comment: This will be exactly the same thing, a string with a `<` character, so it is wrong.

Comment: Apologies. I left the brackets out, I have added this in an edit. The code should work as you intend if you copy paste the above. I have tested this, this morning on one of my projects and it works

Answer (score 0):

to display any characters in `Text` do this

```
<Text>{"Process 1 <-> Process 2"}</Text>
```